# Azure Cognitive Service not working on production mode

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have integrated Azure Cognitive Service's Text to Speech. It is working very well on degug mode. But nothing is happening on production mode. Is there is anything to change when I move from debug to production mode ? Is this because this?

From [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=terminal&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

> Important

> Remember to remove the key from your code when you're done, and never post it publicly. For production, use a secure way of storing and accessing your credentials like Azure Key Vault. See the Cognitive Services security article for more information.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

class Program 
{
    static string YourSubscriptionKey = "YourSubscriptionKey";
    static string YourServiceRegion = "YourServiceRegion";

    static void OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(SpeechSynthesisResult speechSynthesisResult, string text)
    {
        switch (speechSynthesisResult.Reason)
        {
            case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for text: [{text}]");
                break;
            case ResultReason.Canceled:
                var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(speechSynthesisResult);
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(YourSubscriptionKey, YourServiceRegion);      

        // The language of the voice that speaks.
        speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-JennyNeural"; 

        using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
        {
            // Get text from the console and synthesize to the default speaker.
            Console.WriteLine("Enter some text that you want to speak >");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();

            var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
            OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(speechSynthesisResult, text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You then need to pass `YourSubscriptionKey` into the code. I wouldn't bother about `YourServiceRegion` to be honest.

Comment: Hardcoded straight away

Comment: If it's hardcoded in Production, then it should work (don't ask me how I know that!)

Comment: So, hardcoding `YourSubscriptionKey` on production is not a issue right ?

Comment: Well, it’s not ideal. Is this an app service? Environment variables work really well for those.

Answer (score 0):

The production mode will function well when the **Environment Variable Key** using securely stored using **Azure Key Vault.**

Initial step is to get the **Environment Variable key** using the following command

```
using static System.Environment;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Get the named env var, and assign it to the value variable
        var value =
            GetEnvironmentVariable(
                "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_KEY");
    }
}
```

Due to lack of security for the environment variable key, the production mode is not working. If the environment variable key value is stored in Azure key vault, it will function in production mode too.